# A limit with Product and Cosine

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me please to find the limit of this series:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\sqrt[k]{\cos x}\right)}{x^{2n-2}}$$

Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by elementary limits
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt[k]{\cos x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt[k]{\cos x}}{\ln \sqrt[k]{\cos x}}\times \frac{1}{k}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln \cos x}{x^2}=-1\times \left(-\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\frac{1}{2k}$$
and then

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{k=n}1-\sqrt[k]{\cos x}}{x^{2n}}=\prod_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{2^n n!}$$

Chris.

Answer (score 4):

As written, the limit is zero.

$$1-(\cos{x})^{1/k} = \frac{x^2}{2 k} + O(x^4)$$

so that the product is some factor times $x^{2 n}$ in this limit.

However,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{k=n}1-\sqrt[k]{\cos x}}{x^{2n}} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2 k} = \frac{1}{2^n n!}$$

**EDIT**

Justifying the first step:

$$\cos{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \dots$$

$$\begin{align}(\cos{x})^{1/k} &= \left (  1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \dots \right )^{1/k} \end{align}$$

Now use the fact that $(1-z)^{1/k} = 1-\frac{z}{k}+\ldots$ and get

$$\begin{align}(\cos{x})^{1/k} &= \left (  1 - \frac{x^2}{2!k} +\ldots \right )\end{align}$$

Note that the first term that I left out starts with $x^4$.  Then we write, in place of the ellipses, $O(x^4)$ to represent the error which goes to zero as $x \rightarrow 0$. The first step then follows.

Comment: :hi  why $1-(\cos{x})^{1/k} = \frac{x^2}{2 k} + O(x^4)$ and whats  $O(x^4)$

Comment: See the **EDIT** in my answer.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo This is a notation due to Landau. Note it is used extensively in analysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @rlgordonma:thanks i got it